# Trying to grab last $i number of records - getting protected fields?

Tags: php, drupal

I have formulated a query, but when I look at the values, it is going on about protected fields - what am I doing wrong? This is obviously in Drupal.

```
$query
->fields('registration', array('registration_id'))
->range(0, $i)
->orderBy('registration_id', 'desc')
->execute()
->fetchAssoc();
```

Sample:

```
SelectQuery Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Array
        (
            [registration_id] => Array
                (
                    [field] => registration_id
                    [table] => registration
                    [alias] => registration_id
                )

        )

    [expressions:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [tables:protected] => Array
        (
            [registration] => Array
                (
```

etc...

Comment: Earlier in the program. $i = 0;
foreach ($checkboxarray as $entity_id) {

if ($entity_id != 0) {
$i++;
$foreachloop[] = "('reg_type','". (string)$entity_id. "','node', 1, NULL, 0, 'complete',". (string)$timestamp . ",". (string)$timestamp .")";

}

}

Comment: It's reporting correct values when I'm testing it too.